# json_encode remove backslash

Tags: php, html

I get json encoded array from DB change one field and save again but json_encode remove the \ and after I cant see the text in my site.

```
$data_de=json_decode($row["data_json"], true);
$data_de[$ref."_visits"]++;
$datast=json_encode($data_de);
```

for example if before code the value on db was:

```
{"7_id":"7","7_name":"\u05d1\u05d3\u05d94","7_coded":"","7_visits":"0"}
```

after the value:

```
{"7_id":"7","7_name":"u05d1u05d3u05d94","7_coded":"","7_visits":"1"}
```

how I can prevent the removing of backslash?

Comment: What do you mean by *"after the value"* ?

Comment: Double backslashes will be treated as 1 `\\` (backslash) as a string. Without testing it out i cant be sure this information is helpful. In a few languages i've worked in the backslash can have additional meanings hence why double backslashes are required to keep it treated as a string. This is also known as escaping your character.

Comment: the error is not here. the code you provided has no error. but the error is the way you store the string back to database. check there. Here is a [Demo](https://eval.in/783498)

Answer (score 0):

To prevent removing of backslashes use this code in your json encode:

`json_encode($data_de, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

Comment: ***"how I can prevent the removing of backslash?"***